# Questions that provide code that runs with errors

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

Can someone, please, try to check who's right in this post?

[Selecting Plot for Locator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264081/selecting-plot-for-locator/264086?noredirect=1#comment657907_264086)

I maintain that the OP is problematic, as I am running the commands given and I always get errors. I have explained in the comments.

I am just wondering if the rest of you can run the code without errors, or perhaps the OP should be updated.

Comment: 0n my machine, it works fine with on mma version 12.2 but it effectively fails with version 12.0

Comment: Btw : I have *not* upvoted the comment "Please stop distracting from the main issue in this post" wich I find a little rude.

Comment: @andre314 ok so it's not that I am going mad. it does fail for version 12.0. thanks a lot!

Comment: @andre314 I do not mind the comment to be honest. I just wanted this resolved for the quality of the site and future users. All is well it seems :-)

Comment: The code works fine for me on 12.3.1.0 (Windows 10).

Comment: @JimB thanks for the input. I figured it was a version issue.